# Eclipse-hono MQTT adapter: cannot process message

Tags: eclipse-hono

I'm trying to set up hono on my local machine without a container platform.
I've managed to run following services and prerequisites:

- AMQP broker (RabbitMQ)
- InfluxDb
- Hono MQTT adapter
- Hono auth service
- Hono Device registry

When the MQTT adapter starts, I'm getting following logging:

```
14:37:48.257 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.c.RequestResponseClientConfigProperties - loading credentials for [127.0.0.1] from [/media/data/dev/hono-config/mqtt-adapter.credentials]
14:37:48.257 [main] DEBUG o.e.h.a.m.i.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e74ec218 - Waiting 20 seconds for application to start up
14:37:48.258 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.472 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - starting attempt [#1] to connect to server [127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.472 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.473 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - starting attempt [#1] to connect to server [127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.473 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.c.RequestResponseClientConfigProperties - loading credentials for [127.0.0.1] from [/media/data/dev/hono-config/mqtt-adapter.credentials]
14:37:48.473 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.473 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - starting attempt [#1] to connect to server [127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.473 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.c.RequestResponseClientConfigProperties - loading credentials for [127.0.0.1] from [/media/data/dev/hono-config/mqtt-adapter.credentials]
14:37:48.474 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.474 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - starting attempt [#1] to connect to server [127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.474 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672]
14:37:48.474 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - limiting size of inbound message payload to 8096 bytes
14:37:48.474 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] WARN  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - authentication of devices turned off
14:37:48.474 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - Vertx native support: false
14:37:48.476 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - Server uses secure standard port 8883
14:37:48.479 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - OpenSSL [available: false, supports KeyManagerFactory: false]
14:37:48.479 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - using JDK's default SSL engine
14:37:48.480 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - enabling secure protocol [TLSv1.2]
14:37:48.530 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - MQTT server running on 0.0.0.0:8883
14:37:48.530 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - MQTT server running on 0.0.0.0:11883
14:37:48.533 [main] INFO  o.e.h.adapter.mqtt.impl.Application - Started Application in 2.542 seconds (JVM running for 3.01)
14:37:48.608 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connected to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672], opening connection ...
14:37:48.611 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connected to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672], opening connection ...
14:37:48.612 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connected to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672], opening connection ...
14:37:48.612 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connected to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672], opening connection ...
14:37:48.614 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connection to container [rabbit@bob-HP-ZBook-15-G4] at [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672] open
14:37:48.615 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - connected to Tenant service
14:37:48.616 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connection to container [rabbit@bob-HP-ZBook-15-G4] at [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672] open
14:37:48.616 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - connected to Messaging
14:37:48.616 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connection to container [rabbit@bob-HP-ZBook-15-G4] at [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672] open
14:37:48.616 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - connected to Device Registration service
14:37:48.617 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connection to container [rabbit@bob-HP-ZBook-15-G4] at [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672] open
14:37:48.617 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - connected to Credentials service
14:37:48.617 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connected to AMQP 1.0 container [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672], opening connection ...
14:37:48.618 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connection to container [rabbit@bob-HP-ZBook-15-G4] at [amqp://127.0.0.1:5672] open
14:37:48.618 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - connected to Command and Control service
```

When sending a message (mosquitto_pub -p 11883 -t telemetry/DEFAULT_TENANT/4711 -m '{"temp": 5}') to the MQTT adapter (Example taken from https://www.eclipse.org/hono/user-guide/mqtt-adapter/), I'm getting following logging in the MQTT adapter service:

```
14:38:05.208 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - connection request from client [client-id: mosqpub|21426-bob-HP-ZB]
14:38:05.213 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - unauthenticated device [clientId: mosqpub|21426-bob-HP-ZB] connected
14:38:05.215 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.s.m.LoggingConnectionEventProducer -    Connected - ID: mosqpub|21426-bob-HP-ZB, Protocol Adapter: hono-mqtt, Device: null, Data: null
14:38:05.222 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - creating new message sender for telemetry/DEFAULT_TENANT
14:38:05.236 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - creating new client [target: registration/DEFAULT_TENANT]
14:38:05.236 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.RegistrationClientImpl - creating new registration client for [DEFAULT_TENANT]
14:38:05.246 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.c.i.AbstractRequestResponseClient - enabling caching of responses from registration/DEFAULT_TENANT
14:38:05.253 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - creating new client [target: tenant]
14:38:05.254 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.client.impl.TenantClientImpl - creating new tenant client
14:38:05.254 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.h.c.i.AbstractRequestResponseClient - enabling caching of responses from tenant
14:38:05.258 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO  o.e.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl - remote server [127.0.0.1:5672] closed connection with error condition: The connections default session closed unexpectedly: : io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Error{condition=amqp:invalid-field, description='Attach rejected: {unknown_destination,"telemetry/DEFAULT_TENANT"}', info=null}
14:38:05.260 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - cannot process message [endpoint: telemetry] from device [tenantId: DEFAULT_TENANT, deviceId: 4711]
org.eclipse.hono.client.ServerErrorException: no connection to service
    at org.eclipse.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl.lambda$getOrCreateSender$16(HonoClientImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl.failAllCreationRequests(HonoClientImpl.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl.clearState(HonoClientImpl.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl.handleConnectionLoss(HonoClientImpl.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl.onRemoteClose(HonoClientImpl.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.hono.client.impl.HonoClientImpl.lambda$connect$2(HonoClientImpl.java:372)
    at io.vertx.proton.impl.ProtonConnectionImpl.lambda$getDefaultSession$6(ProtonConnectionImpl.java:256)
    at io.vertx.proton.impl.ProtonSessionImpl.fireRemoteClose(ProtonSessionImpl.java:270)
    at io.vertx.proton.impl.ProtonTransport.handleSocketBuffer(ProtonTransport.java:125)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl$DataMessageHandler.handle(NetSocketImpl.java:384)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.handleMessageReceived(NetSocketImpl.java:351)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl$1.handleMessage(NetClientImpl.java:242)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl$1.handleMessage(NetClientImpl.java:239)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.lambda$channelRead$1(VertxHandler.java:146)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:195)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
14:38:05.261 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.a.m.i.VertxBasedMqttProtocolAdapter - discarding message [topic: telemetry/DEFAULT_TENANT/4711] from device: no connection to service
```

Which service is it trying to connect to?
A small question off topic: in the docker_swarm.sh I also noticed the messaging service, what is used for? On https://www.eclipse.org/hono/getting-started/#starting-hono it is not mentioned.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hono doesn't (officially) support RabbitMQ as the AMQP 1.0 Messaging Network. However, based on Rabbit's support for AMQP 1.0, you may still get it to work. That said, it looks like the MQTT adapter cannot open a sender link to Rabbit which seems to reject the adapter's request to open a sender on target address `telemetry/DEFAULT_TENANT`. This might be due to Rabbit's *origins* as a message broker which requires to define *queues* and/or *topics* before they can be used during runtime.

I am no expert in RabbitMQ but I think you should figure out

- how to configure RabbitMQ so that it *dynamically* creates queues/topics during runtime when a corresponding link is opened by a peer, or
- define the corresponding queues in RabbitMQ upfront, e.g. by means of adding them to Rabbit's configuration file(s).

If it is not imperative to use RabbitMQ, I would actually recommend to use Qpid Dispatch Router together with Apache MQ Artemis instead. You will get better support from the Hono dev team for it, because that's the *official* implementation of the AMQP Messaging Network being used for development.

Regarding your side note: Before Hono 0.7, all Protocol Adapters had to connect to the Messaging service, which provided a central point in the message flow where Hono could verify the origin of a telemetry message or event before forwarding it downstream to the AMQP Messaging Network (and hence the consuming applications).

For this purpose, a protocol adapter needed to include in each message a JSON Web Token which it obtained from the Device Registration service for a connected device and which asserted the device's registration status. Hono Messaging would then verify the JWT's signature, thus ensuring that the message origins from an existing (registered) device of a tenant that the protocol adapter is actually enabled for. The idea was that the Device Registry would not issue a JWT for a device that the adapter was not authorized for. This is particularly useful for scenarios where a *custom* (third party provided) protocol adapter should be integrated with a Hono installation (e.g. for a particular tenant) but that protocol adapter should be prevented from sending messages downstream on behalf or arbitrary devices that do not belong to the tenant that the adapter has been authorized for.

In more recent versions we dropped this component in favor of authorizing the protocol adapters at the AMQP Messaging Network.

### Logging

All Hono services log information to standard out. The log level can be set by means of the `spring.profiles.active` Java system property. If not set, the services will log at INFO level, just providing very limited information about the lifecycle events the component is going through.
In order to turn on more exhaustive debug logging, set the system property like this `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` when starting the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I installed ActiveMQ Artemis and it worked.
Some remarks:
- Wouldn't it be useful to mention the remark you made about the messaging service somewhere in the hono documentation?
- If I'm not mistaking, nothing is mentioned about the use of a specific AMQP 1.0 broker. Would be nice to have some information on that somewhere.
- I'm trying to set up hono and ditto (with custom functionality in between). Maybe I can give some feedback to update information?
- Small setback: now I'm getting a request timeout , but I cannot find to which service, it is not logged.

Comment: when you say "I'm getting a request timeout", which component do you mean? The device (i.e. the MQTT client)?

Comment: No, the MQTT Adapter service is getting it. I think it is waiting for a response from the device registry. But this is nowhere logged. So it's just a guess.

Comment: you can turn on logging in the MQTT adapter and the Device Registry as described in my answer. We should then be able to track down the problem ...

Comment: I'm working the other way around now. I've setup the docker environment and got the mqtt adapter out of the docker environment. i'm running it locally now. It connects and communicates with the rest of hono. Will try and get everything up and running this way. Thanks for the assitance!